# mvn liquibase rollback returns type incompatibility error

Tags: maven, liquibase

My Spring Boot api utilizes liquibase and I'm trying to roll back the last liquibase update.

I've tried a couple different commands (followed by my db credentials on the same line):

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1
```

and also:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackDate=2022-11-08
```

For each, the mvn execution starts out promising, with `Successfully acquired change lock`

But then each ends up with this error:

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:rollback (default-cli) on project tve: A type incompatibility occurred while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:rollback: java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I notice that the most recent rows in my `databasechangelog` table show a liquibase version of `4.5.0`, while all the older ones show `3.5.4`. Perhaps that's somehow related to this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was able to resolve this by changing my liquibase-maven-plugin version from 3.4.1 to 4.5.0.

Not exactly sure what the issue was or why that resolved it, but perhaps this may help someone else.